# spring-kafka listener shutdown

Tags: spring-kafka

I'm trying to verify that kafka-listeners are closed gracefully when i shutdown my application (either gracefully or in some aggressive way). Can somebody point me to place where it is handled? I was looking at `destroy` and `close` methods but I couldn't locate where kafka client deregistration is actually happening.

What happens if deregistration takes too much time? Or if some other spring bean shutdown hook takes too much time?

Also what it actually means for currently processing events? Can they commit offset during shutdown if they happen to finish their work?

I'm working with spring-kafka 1.3.5 version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current 1.3.x version is 1.3.8; you should upgrade. 1.3.9 will be released early January.

When you `stop()` a listener container, the container will stop in an orderly fashion and process any records that have previously returned by a `pol()` (but no further polls will be made). However, you should ensure your listener will process any remaining records within the shutdownTimeout (default 10 seconds, but configurable). The `stop()` operation will block for that time, waiting for the container(s) to stop.

With more modern versions (2.2.x, currently 2.2.2) you can use an `ApplicationListener` or `@EventListener` to consume `ContainerStoppedEvent`.

Comment: So, when I kill spring application, then - during destroying spring application context - `stop()` method is called on all kafka containers and spring also waits until containers finish stopping? I know this is probably spring-related - I suppose there is some limit also for spring  -  do you know how long does spring itself wait?

Comment: Kill in what way? The JVM is killed immediately with `kill -9` so there is no orderly shutdown. With a sigterm kill, the application context will be closed normally; Spring waits for up to 30 seconds before giving up. It's not the end of the world if you use ackmode record, since any uncommitted record offsets will be re-sent when you next start the app.

Comment: @GaryRussell Configuring shutdownTimeout seems to be broken when you use spring-cloud-stream (1.2.X) `@StreamListener`